# Firebase issue with Apple Sign-In re-authentication

Tags: swift, firebase-authentication, apple-sign-in

I need to add functionality to delete a user from the application. I use firebase and only Apple provider is used for registration and authorization.
When I try to re-authenticate a user using `Auth.auth().currentUser?.reauthenticate(with:)` I always get an error:

`error: Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17094 "Duplicate credential received. Please try again with a new credential." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Duplicate credential received. Please try again with a new credential., FIRAuthErrorUserInfoNameKey=ERROR_MISSING_OR_INVALID_NONCE}`

Here is the code I am using to delete a user:

```
func deleteAccountApple() async throws {
    guard let user = Auth.auth().currentUser else {
        throw AccountDeletionError.notSignedIn
    }
    do {
        try await user.delete()
    } catch {
        let nsError = error as NSError
        let authError = AuthErrorCode.Code(rawValue: nsError.code)

        if authError == .requiresRecentLogin {
            do {
                try await reauthenticateFirebaseUser()
                try await user.delete()
            } catch {
                throw AccountDeletionError.failedToDeleteFirebaseAccount(error)
            }
        } else {
            throw AccountDeletionError.failedToDeleteFirebaseAccount(error)
        }
    }
}

private func reauthenticateFirebaseUser() async throws {
    guard let user = Auth.auth().currentUser else {
        throw AccountDeletionError.notSignedIn
    }

    let idToken = try await user.getIDToken()
    let nonce: String = .randomNonceString
  
    let credentials = OAuthProvider.credential(
        withProviderID: "apple.com",
        idToken: idToken,
        rawNonce: nonce
    )

    try await user.reauthenticate(with: credentials)
}
```

How to get valid credentials to re-authenticate a user who is logged in with Apple?

I would appreciate any help!

I have tried to generate a new `nonce` and also tried to save and use the same `nonce` as when the user was authorized but I always get the error.

Comment: you have to get it from the user by showing apple’s view not use an old one from storage. I believe the login info can’t be more than 10 min old. The nonce doesn’t have anything to do with this, the nonce is just to make sure that the response is legitimate.

Answer (score 0):

Use the most recent OAuthProvider.credential that is not older than 10 minutes. During the re-authentication process, according to their official integration documentation, you are required to use the most recent sign-in, which means you must review the apple sign-in prompt again before performing any sensitive action such as deleting an account.

Error message giving information : `Please try again with a new credential`

> The same pattern can be used with reauthenticateWithCredential(),
> which you can use to retrieve a fresh credential for sensitive
> operations that `require recent sign-in`

for more reference refer this official doc with [Reauthentication and account linking](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/apple#reauthentication_and_account_linking).